# "Show iteration count" on XCode 8.3.3 does not show the indication on the respective files

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

Although I have enabled the option "Show iteration count" on XCode 8.3.3

[image: Iteration counts]

XCode does not display the count on the respective files after I have performed the tests on the project.

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found that it works when you go to the report navigator, select the respective test and then open the files from there.

Also "Gather coverage data" has to be checked

[image: Gather coverage data]